# What login screen program will 11.04 use?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, 11.04, gnome

Will Ubuntu continue using that old (GNOME 2.X) login screen, or create its own, or there will be a new one in Gnome 3?

Comment: GDM was totally rewritten just recently, so it isn't the *old* GNOME 2 login screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an intention to [replace GDM with LightDM](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-display-manager) in Natty+1; some details [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UDSProceedings/N/PackageSelectionAndSystemDefaults#Use%20LightDM%20for%20display%20management). As things stand, LightDM is set to be in Universe in Natty and usable as a GDM alternative, but the default will be GDM.

Comment: "Not proposed for natty, due to Unity changes, Will be in natty universe, and usable as an alternative display manager, Will re-propose for natty+1"

Answer (score 0):

Unity is based on Gnome, so I suppose that Ubuntu will continue to use Gnome Display Manager (GDM).